# How to access values in data frame when column data repeats itself using R?

Tags: r

Using the following dummy data, column B tells whether a gate was open (1) or not (0). The data is reported on a timeline. Number of occurring cells in open and closed state varies in the dataset, sometimes it can be a few, sometimes it can be 30 or more cells in a row.

```
set.seed(123)
x <- NULL
x$A <- runif(100, -1, 1)
x <- as.data.frame(x)
x$B <- c(rep(1, 4), rep(0,5), rep(1, 15), rep(0,30), rep(1,18), rep(0,12), rep(1,16)) # May start with 0 as well

> head(x)
           A B
1 -0.4248450 1
2  0.5766103 1
3 -0.1820462 1
4  0.7660348 1
5  0.8809346 0
6 -0.9088870 0
```

I want to access the data in Column A for **each** open or closed series of B, in order to calculate mean, sum, etc of A. Also how can I access the data in col A of the n:th open or closed series of B?

So far I have used loops to count and identify the open and closed series - but that requires a fixed number of repeats in each series which is not usable in this type of dataset.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most elegant solution (there may be a fully `dplyr` alternative that scales better if that is an issue, but my proposed solution is to lag `B` by one unit and the identify places where `B` and `lag(B)` are different - this is a place where `B` changes from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0.  Then, you can run a for loop over the entire data frame identifying where the change happens and increment a `spell` counter at the change point.

```
set.seed(123)
x <- NULL
x$A <- runif(100, -1, 1)
x <- as.data.frame(x)
x$B <- c(rep(1, 4), rep(0,5), rep(1, 15), rep(0,30), rep(1,18), rep(0,12), rep(1,16)) # May start with 0 as well

## first lag (move previous iteration forward) B and 
## create the difference between B and its previous observation
## Then, also fill in the first observation which will have
## missing delta with zero - simply indicating that the first 
## observation is not a change from the previous one. 
x <- x %>% mutate(delta = B - lag(B), 
                  delta = ifelse(is.na(delta), 0, delta))
```

The resulting data frame looks like the one below.  Note that `delta` is zero except for places where `B` switches from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0.

```
head(x)
#           A B delta
#1 -0.4248450 1     0
#2  0.5766103 1     0
#3 -0.1820462 1     0
#4  0.7660348 1     0
#5  0.8809346 0    -1
#6 -0.9088870 0     0
```

Next, we can initialize a variable called `spell`, which will essentially hold an identification number for the times of consistent values on `B`.  Based on the data above, we would expect observations 1 to 4 in `x` to have value `1` on `spell` because they are all instances where `B` is one and are not separated by any instances of `B` equal to zero.  That `spell variable should switch to` 2` for observations 5-10 and so on.

```
x$spell <- NA
```

We initialize a counter `k` that will hold the spell identification number.

```
k <- 1
```

Next, we loop over the rows of `x`, we want to increment `k` by 1 for observations where `B` switches from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0 (i.e., places where `delta` is not equal to zero).  Then we replace `spell` with that same value of `k` until there is another switch in `B`.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
  if(x$delta[i] != 0)k <- k+1
  x$spell[i] <- k
}
```

We can use `dplyr` to group observations together and create various summaries like means or standard deviations:

```
x %>% group_by(spell, B) %>% summarise(m=mean(A), s = sd(A))
# `summarise()` regrouping output by 'spell' (override with `.groups` argument)
# # A tibble: 7 x 4
# # Groups:   spell [7]
#   spell     B       m     s
#   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1  0.184  0.577
# 2     2     0  0.183  0.718
# 3     3     1  0.188  0.632
# 4     4     0 -0.121  0.554
# 5     5     1  0.0933 0.520
# 6     6     0 -0.170  0.494
# 7     7     1 -0.0471 0.607
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, it works elegantly. Can you explain the details of the code, I don't understand what it does?

Comment: @pha I added some explanation in the answer about what the code is doing.